# Transfering to a page in asp.net when routes are applied in webForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am using something like

```
server.transfer("~/student/Language-Certificate");
```

in a click event.
but I get this error "Error executing child request for /Students/Language-Certificate."

note: from code behind something like this

```
MenuItem country = new MenuItem();
country.NavigateUrl = "~/Admin/Country/Add";
```

works fine.

how to use routes with server.transfer so that it redirects properly to the clean url address ?

Comment: According to [this article's](http://forums.asp.net/t/1458709.aspx/1) accepted answer `Server.Transfer` bypasses routing, but a work-around is offered there.

Comment: thanks for the link I saw it .. couldn't extract anything useful about it .... I gave up using Server.Transfer ... instead I am using Response.RedirectToRoute() ...

Answer (score 1):

I have used

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("NameOfTheRoute");
```

and it works fine.

thanks to :  http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1450-aspnet-40-routing.aspx